# Why does the figure show black image only in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, convolution

I learn about convolution and wrote a program like this:

```
gambar = imread('adidas.jpg');
imshow(gambar);
mask = [-1 -1 -1; -1 -8 -1; -1 -1 -1];
gray = rgb2gray(gambar);
thresh =  graythresh(gray);
imbw = im2bw(gray,thresh);
hasil = conv2(double(imbw),mask,'valid');
figure;
imshow(hasil);
```

The Image i took :
[image]

I expect the output to be something like this:
[image]

But, I just got **black** image. Why? Is it related with the version of Matlab I use or something else?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with your code but, the results are in the range `-16`  to `0` For the `double` image `0` is black `1` (or anything above 1) is white. so you should change the code like this: `mask = [-1 -1 -1; -1 -8 -1; -1 -1 -1]./-16` so that the matrix `hasil` will be withing the range `0-1`. Still you wont get your desired results. you would get an image similar to `imbw`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have figured out why after I saw your comment :D

Comment: Its nice that you have figured it out.. kindly post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.. :)

Comment: I want to mark it as an answer but I don't see 'Mark as an answer' button.

Comment: Actually i asked you to post the answer you came up with and mark that answer.

Comment: Normally `imshow` will only display intensities from 0 to 1 with `double` numbers. Use `imshow(hasil,[])` for automatic intensity scaling.